# Deploy Angular app plus vertx: what's best?

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, vert.x

I have the current configuration:

- a GUI team develops the Angular app in a separate project and builds all TypeScript stuff to produce the final UI app.
- another team has Vert.x java library in the server app to do REST service and produces a final fat jar.

I wonder what's the best approach to deliver GUI and backend in one shot:

Is is ok to have 1 jar for backend and Gui (say a directory call "app") both in the same folder? Can vert.x access resources outside its jar?

Do I have to put GUI in the same maven project where my vert.x REST services are developped, run the "ng build" commands from maven, and package all in one jar?

I'm a bit confused here.

Any of you are in the same situation, what's your advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer Flash. I actually tried to have at the same level my fat jar along with the "app" folder containing the compiled angular app and it's actually working well (but you have to run the java command in the folder containing the jar)

Answer (score 1):

> All it's upto you how do you wanna deploy it on production ;)

**First approach**

You can create one fat.jar to deliver everything in it -> so it  will include angular static build files (under webroot) and then all your vert.x related  code.

**Second approach**

You can create one fat.jar just with angular static files exposed using vert.x and also you can integrate authentication (cas/saml) in the same and another fat.jar will have rest implementation (connecting to database or WebService consumption ). So you will have two fat.jar and it will be best if you are planning for clustering and for hazel cast structure.

We have already tested both approaches and both are working great but Right now we are following second approach !!